# How to use Shared ViewModel in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger, dagger-hilt

I want to make a ViewModel shared between multiple fragments
we try it before hilt and it works fine
but after hilt ViewModel is created twice

my question is how to get the same  ViewModel each time   with the hilt

```
@HiltViewModel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For shared VM you use `viewModel by activityViewModels<MyViewModel>()` in fragment . Never create a Singleton `ViewModel` this kind of defeat the purpose of having `ViewModel` .

This extension comes from fragment ktx library . you can add it with following dependency.

```
 def activity_version = "1.2.0"
 def fragment_version = "1.3.0"
 implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$activity_version"
 implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"
```

When you inject it you can use the it as :

```
 @AndroidEntryPoint
class MyFragment : Fragment(){
    private val viewModel by activityViewModels<MyViewModel>()
}
```